# How do you make the unicode Bitcoin symbol show correctly in text on Linux?

Tags: linux, bitcoin-symbol

The Bitcoin symbol was added to the Unicode standard as ₿ (U+20BF). This shows up as a placeholder (empty box) in texts for me. What do you have to do so it will be shown in text, e.g. in the browser?

Comment: How old is your Linux installation?  Mine (Debian buster) shows the character properly.  I can open gedit, type Ctrl-Shift-U 20bf space, and see the proper character.

Comment: This machine is running Ubuntu 18.04

Answer (score 19, accepted):

While the symbol was part of the Unicode 10.0 release, many fonts still don't have the symbol as part of their character set. You need to install a font that includes the symbol to make it show up.

One such font is [`GNU Unifont Glyphs`](http://unifoundry.com/unifont/index.html). After installing the package `unifont`, the symbol shows up in the console and browser for me.

---

Corollary, many Linux distributions support inputting unicode symbols by typing `CTRL+SHIFT+U`, followed by the symbol's designation `20bf` offset by a space or `ENTER`.

Comment: You will not get this issue with Ubuntu 20.04 LTS, where unifont is included by default.

If you run into some display weirdness with the ùnifont` package, try `apt-get install xfonts-unifont ttf-unifont` these packages are supposed to display font in TrueType and PCF (bitmap) method.